# Technical information about the iPhone touchscreen controller?

Tags: iphone, driver, touchscreen

I want to make a driver for low-level access to the iPhone's touchscreen controller, the Texas Instruments TI 343S0538, so I can try to detect fingerprints. However, I can't seem to find any information about it, because [the Google search results](http://google.com/search?q=TI+343S0538+-iphone) don't return much information, apart from lots of pages showing the iPhone specs.

So does anyone know anything about the controller, or is it secret because it's used by Apple?

Comment: It's a custom chip. TI doesn't publish tech docs on custom chip designed for their clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Global nomad said in the comments, this seems to be a custom chip, and their website doesn’t contain any information on the chip.

However, ABI Research has a teardown of the chip, although I don’t know how comprehensive or thorough it is. The (paid) report can be found at http://www.abiresearch.com/research/1009855. The list of the documents in the report reads “Specification”. This could be provided by Texas Instruments, or it could be compiled by ABI.

The search results on the website say, "This file is not available to the public, but it is available for purchase.” There isn’t an obvious buy button, so it’s possible that we can’t purchase it. But that might be worth chasing up — that’s the best that I can fine.